# Is there a way to send notifications automatically when there is changes in data of firebase realtime database using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using firebase realtime database in my app and i want to send fixed notifications automatically when there is a changed in realtime database but firebase cloud messaging only offers manual sending of notifications which does not meet the real-time monitoring objective of my app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay that's the problem I was facing while making my Chat app.

There are two ways to send real-time notification using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

*1.Through firebase console.*

*2.Using API provided by firebase for FCM.*

**Read about the API below:**

1.https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages

2.https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send

So when there is a change in data realtime DB of Firebase you should make a post request to the given API,and the API automatically send notification to the respective person with a particular FCM token.

**For step by step implementation,read the medium article below .**

https://selvaganesh93.medium.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-important-rest-apis-be79260022b5

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using FCM. By simply sending POST requests with some parameters from your server.

Here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: My only problem with this is that my project does not include an admin or servers.